# How to create private chain in trinity / py-evm?

Tags: private-blockchain, py-evm, trinity

I am doing academic research using ethereum and want to use trinity / py-evm for the same.

I have installed trinity and py-evm now next steps for me is to create a private chain and write some application code in python that runs on the private chain.

However I am not able to find a tutorial to init private chain. From trinity command help it seems it does not support private chain.

Can someone please provide me any tutorial link to follow for the same ?
Thanks in advance.